# Jquery ajax function returns wrong webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 local servers connected to a local switch. Ip adresses: 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.20. I am trying to get some data from the second one to the first using jquery Ajax as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("button").click(function(){ 
        $.ajax({              
            type: "GET",  
            url: "192.168.0.20/d",   
            dataType: '', 
            success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {    
            console.log(response);  
            window.alert(response);
            }   
        });  
    }); 
}); 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<button id="get-button">Toggle</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

When I put "192.168.0.20/d" in the browser url I get "data = xyz" as expected but using the method above I get that exact script back, its returning itself(192.168.0.10) instead of 192.168.0.20. How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Edit.
The following gets rid of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error but the returned data does not appear in the message box but it is present in developer mode.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET", 
    crossDomain: true,  
    dataType: "JSONP",  
    url: "//192.168.0.20/d", 
    success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { 
    console.log(response);  
    window.alert(response);  
 }
```

[image]

Comment: When you put this url in browser what response you get 192.168.0.10?

Comment: When I put "192.168.0.20/d" into the browser get "data = xyz", this is correct. When I put "192.168.0.10" I get the above html. When this button is clicked (which implements requesting 192.168.0.20/d) it should display "data = xyz" in the alert window but instead its displaying the complete script above, as if "192.168.0.10" was in the url field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alter your URL to:

```
url: "//192.168.0.20/d"
```

The way you've specified it now is as a *relative* URL. In other words it will assume that you want to make the request to the current domain, and that 192.168.0.20 is a subfolder of your website. You'd have the same problem if you created a hyperlink to it - it's not an ajax issue, it's the way browsers interpret URL fragments. This normally helps programmers when deploying the same site to multiple environments (e.g. dev, test, live) on different servers, so they don't have to replace all the URLs to point to a different place just because the deployed location changed. However in this case you're pointing to a resource on another server entirely, so that situation doesn't apply.

If you place the `//` before it, this indicates that it's an *absolute* URL (so always points to exactly the same place, no matter where the originating page is deployed) and that the first part following the slashes is a domain name or IP address.

(N.B. The `//` without `http:` or `https:` before it means that the browser will use the same protocol as the originating page is currently running under. So if your page is loaded via HTTP it'll make the ajax request via HTTP too, and if your page is loaded via HTTPS it'll make the ajax request via HTTPS. If that's not suitable for this scenario then you can add `http:` or `https:` at the beginning as appropriate.)

Look at https://jsfiddle.net/9uyuj96f/ (your code) and https://jsfiddle.net/9uyuj96f/1/ (fixed version) and watch the ajax request in the browser's network tools to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Making this adjustment gave me a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. I made some edits to the original code (in edited answer) which got rid of the errors. I can now see the returned data in developer mode but it will not create a message box. Why might this  be (or not be) happening?

Comment: what does "it will not" mean? You get an error of any kind? BTW your response `data = 22` does not look like JSON or JSONP. That could be causing an issue.

Comment: As you said it is expecting JSONP because ajax is forcing me to use that parameter in the code. If I set that to 'text' or 'html' I get the cross domain error. Now both servers are connected locally to the same network and are within the same domain so shouldn't have this issue. How is ajax setup so that it knows it is the same domain?

Comment: different IP or server name = different domain as far as CORS is concerned. so server1.example.com is considered a different domain from server2.example.com . And also if the ports are different, even on the same server, this also is considered different. There is nothing you can do to change that, except you can change the remote server to allow CORS requests, or change it so that the output is valid JSONP content

Comment: I changed the server header to to allow the requests and can easily parse the JSON data so all is good. I may change the formatting to JSONP in the future but i'm fine for now. Thanks for all the good advice.

Comment: Ok, good, although `data = 22` (as you mentioned the output being) is not JSON

Comment: I'v changed it since. :)

Comment: Good idea. BTW please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you - thanks :-)